# button do everything, it is really?

Tags: system-installation

successfully installed (manually) ubuntu on the desktop. installed the required packages and configured the configuration files. Now Ubuntu is part of the Microsoft Active Directory. everything works correctly. the distributed file system is connected, the bootloader is password protected. all this took about an hour. Is it possible to make it all automated? - jointly, and the installation of the system, and packages, and setting up the config files? I know that there is puppet, but for example puppet razor pxe, it don’t must work, since there is already a pxe server in the ms system center

I decided to Supplement the question to change its current status: 1. There is a corporate network where the main operating system and all infrastructure solutions (DFS, DNS, DC, Mail, etc.) are based on MS Windows. However, few users like Linux.I want to allow them to use linux, but not deprive them of the ability to use the infrastructure. In the case of Echange, the perfect solution is Evolution + ecolution ews. I was faced with a difficulty. Installing and configuring the Windows operating system with System Center takes a few minutes and is fully automated. In the case of Linux and manual installation, a large amount of time is required. However, I am aware of the possibilities available for automating these processes in linux as well. Fai slishkom is a specific project. Is it possible to manually prepare an analog of SC in Linuxe? In my opinion, local repositories in Linux are more convenient than WSUS, Pxe server Linux is also possible, and there is a whole galaxy of different automation scripts. Is it possible to create a sequence when installing Linux? What format should the image itself be in when installing? There are a number of issues that need to be addressed... documentations. Would you be so kind as to suggest a book about linux as an infrastructure solution ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no single button to magically do everything, but there are several ways to avoid repeating tasks like installing packages and configurations.

1. You can take an image of your Ubuntu partition with `dd`, something like `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/my/ubuntu.img` (sda1 is an example), and whenever you need to set up a new system, just write the image back to the new disk. And it will be a clone of the original.
2. You can set up a [docker container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)). You can think of docker as basically a thin layer on top of the OS that manages file system, packages, and configurations. It is created for situations like this. Let's say you create a container, and inside it create a development environment with very specific commands and steps. Then you can just run this container from different machines and get this exact environment.
3. Use [FAI (Fully Automated Installation)](https://fai-project.org/) (thanks to Karel for this link). From their website, "FAI is a tool for unattended mass deployment of Linux. It's a system to install and configure Linux systems and software packages on computers". Head over to the [FAI guide](https://fai-project.org/fai-guide/) to learn how it works.

Comment: https://fai-project.org/ Fully Automatic Installation is a tool for unattended mass deployment of Linux. It's a system to install and configure Linux systems and software packages on computers as well as virtual machines, from small labs to large-scale infrastructures like clusters and virtual environments. You can take one or more virgin PC's, turn on the power, and after a few minutes, the systems are installed, and completely configured to your exact needs, without any interaction necessary.

Comment: @karel that's very useful. I didn't know such a thing exists. It may be worth it to add this as a separate answer to this question. Feel free to edit mine as well.

Comment: I don't want to answer this question because maybe it's a duplicate of another question. The problem is I don't know which question should be the primary question and which other questions should be the signposts to it (depending on the quality of the answers), so you can grab the FAI link and edit your own answer with it. If you want this to be the primary question you're going to need to download FAI and report in detail about your experiences with it.

Comment: @imurD You could try `dd` from a live Ubuntu session when the disk you want to clone is not mounted.